# Facebook sms notifications. I received. A friend request on? My phone SMS but when I went into Facebook it's not there

Tags: facebook, sms

I received a Facebook SMS notification with a friend request when I went into Facebook. The request is not there how can I find out? Why I got the SMS message notification but not? The. One on the Facebook app? And it's not? Anywhere in. My activity log.